# Tomcat 7 startup problems: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory

Tags: java, tomcat

Alright. At one point I had Tomcat (7) working fine. Now it's not. I don't know what I might have messed up. (But I think it happened as I was setting up a web-project in NetBeans to work with Tomcat.)

I'm on OS X 1.8.5, using Java 1.7.0_51.

My catalina.out looks like this:

```
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.29 using APR version 1.5.0.
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013)
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8089"]
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1761 ms
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Users/Edvard/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/docs
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory /Users/Edvard/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/docs
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(ContextConfig.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:836)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1229)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.idFor(DigesterFactory.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.<clinit>(DigesterFactory.java:59)
    ... 18 more

Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Users/Edvard/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/examples
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory /Users/Edvard/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/examples
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(ContextConfig.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:836)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1229)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Users/Edvard/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/host-manager
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory /Users/Edvard/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/host-manager
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(ContextConfig.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:836)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1229)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Users/Edvard/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/manager
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory /Users/Edvard/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/manager
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(ContextConfig.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:836)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1229)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Users/Edvard/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory /Users/Edvard/Downloads/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/webapps/ROOT
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.createWebXmlDigester(ContextConfig.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.init(ContextConfig.java:836)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1229)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8089"]
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Feb 23, 2014 5:42:58 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 409 ms
```

I have tried reinstalling Tomcat, but the problem persists. I'd be very thankful for any pointers I could get.

Comment: This is off-topic for SO. Please read the [FAQ] and [Ask].  Maybe appropriate for [webmasters.se] or [sf].

Comment: Sounds like you may have editted one of Tomcat's xml configuration files and possibly gotten something wrong.  The 'digester' is an component that reads the xml files and create the related object configuration, but if you get something out of wack in the xml file, it can cause what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I can't see how that could be a problem when it gives me the exact same error on a fresh installation of tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same exact problem happened to me.You probably have downloaded your own servlet.jar file instead of using tomcat's. Check out your /Library/Java/Extensions/ folder (or whatever folder you put the jar file), and delete the servlet.jar file. Catalina run, it should work now