# Error running Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I get the following error when i try to run the spring boot application in eclipse by "Run as->Java Application" by right clicking the Aplication.java file. Don't know what is the problem. 
Please help.

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.0.2.RELEASE)

2015-07-05 12:36:05.817  INFO 2994 --- [           main] org.magnum.dataup.Application            : Starting Application on binays-MacBook-Pro.local with PID 2994 (/Users/binay/Desktop/android_part1/android5/mobilecloud-15-master-2/assignments/assignment2/bin started by binay in /Users/binay/Desktop/android_part1/android5/mobilecloud-15-master-2/assignments/assignment2)
2015-07-05 12:36:05.820 DEBUG 2994 --- [           main] org.magnum.dataup.Application            : Running with Spring Boot v1.0.2.RELEASE, Spring v4.0.3.RELEASE
2015-07-05 12:36:05.889  INFO 2994 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7116fe10: startup date [Sun Jul 05 12:36:05 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-07-05 12:36:06.856  INFO 2994 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2015-07-05 12:36:08.291  INFO 2994 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6702707c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-07-05 12:36:08.355  INFO 2994 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionAttributeSource' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-07-05 12:36:08.389  INFO 2994 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'transactionInterceptor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-07-05 12:36:08.397  INFO 2994 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.BeanFactoryTransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2015-07-05 12:36:08.759  INFO 2994 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: 8080
2015-07-05 12:36:09.057  INFO 2994 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2015-07-05 12:36:09.057  INFO 2994 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
2015-07-05 12:36:09.109 ERROR 2994 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.createTldDigester(TldConfig.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.init(TldConfig.java:576)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig.lifecycleEvent(TldConfig.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.idFor(DigesterFactory.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.DigesterFactory.<clinit>(DigesterFactory.java:59)
    ... 15 common frames omitted

2015-07-05 12:36:09.111 ERROR 2994 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:79)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at org.magnum.dataup.Application.main(Application.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:799)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 common frames omitted

2015-07-05 12:36:09.181  INFO 2994 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/Users/binay/Desktop/android_part1/android5/mobilecloud-15-master-2/assignments/assignment2/bin/, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/83cd2cd674a217ade95a4bb83a8a14f351f48bd0/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/235ba8b489512805ac13a8f9ea77a1ca5ebe3e8/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.1.2/b316e9737eea25e9ddd6d88eaeee76878045c6b2/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.1.2/2d23694879c2c12f125dac5076bdfd5d771cc4cb/logback-core-1.1.2.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.3.0/f5e853a20b60758922453d56f9ae1e64af5cb3da/jackson-annotations-2.3.0.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.3.3/7d8c5d79cc99995e21e6f955857312d8409f02a1/jackson-core-2.3.3.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.3.3/63b77400b5f1cf83a81823562c48d3120ef5518e/jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.github.davidmarquis/fluent-interface-proxy/1.3.0/519c459c771e2554437649a32b56e27a83ba66dc/fluent-interface-proxy-1.3.0.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.2.4/a60a5e993c98c864010053cb901b7eab25306568/gson-2.2.4.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.guava/guava/17.0/9c6ef172e8de35fd8d4d8783e4821e57cdef7445/guava-17.0.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.h2database/h2/1.3.175/408ed316edddbce6db031c6bdceee73a09647d9e/h2-1.3.175.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.squareup.retrofit/retrofit/1.6.0/39a9e4b49ded46aa1b67d492fe287c4cebcd815c/retrofit-1.6.0.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.9.2/7a87d845ad3a155297e8f67d9008f4c1e5656b71/commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/9ce04e34240f674bc72680f8b843b1457383161a/commons-codec-1.9.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/761ea405b9b37ced573d2df0d1e3a4e0f9edc668/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/b1b6ea3b7e4aa4f492509a4952029cd8e48019ad/commons-io-2.4.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/f6f66e966c70a83ffbdb6f17a0919eaf7c8aca7f/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/5d3ccc056b6f056dbf0dddfdf43894b9065a8f94/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/junit/junit/4.11/4e031bb61df09069aeb2bffb4019e7a5034a4ee0/junit-4.11.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.3.2/90a3822c38ec8c996e84c16a3477ef632cbc87a3/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core/7.0.52/b4afc2f8e00a43c8dd6bb289473ad1c30de59909/tomcat-embed-core-7.0.52.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-el/7.0.52/d5376b041a0c56c4d7e6c21d91ce9add9cb0283c/tomcat-embed-el-7.0.52.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/7.0.52/3c81b2aee6d0c6d2eafa18ad9c7c9144d302c675/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-7.0.52.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/7.0.52/f46429c816f5bac0e7099b9290183287c79cf538/tomcat-jdbc-7.0.52.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-juli/7.0.52/6f81f6b2630f2d1f1478c9f9eac8332012b56d9c/tomcat-juli-7.0.52.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjrt/1.7.4/e49a5c0acee8fd66225dc1d031692d132323417f/aspectjrt-1.7.4.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.7.4/d9d511e417710492f78bb0fb291a629d56bf4216/aspectjweaver-1.7.4.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.atteo/evo-inflector/1.0.1/a66d33e82d12f4a96542198ba1a58c87fb30059f/evo-inflector-1.0.1.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-core/1.3/42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.3/4785a3c21320980282f9f33d0d1264a69040538f/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.4.Final/f1af75eca4e13ac0578750a497159695feceebfc/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/5e731d961297e5a07290bfaf3db1fbc8bbbf405a/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.1.Final/73618cbf2dd1fa989a13d9444d4f025cfc51ec10/hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.1.Final/c27f33216ed0d0351f1ecf6a5b6f6c490b4bcbb9/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.1.Final.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/d9a09f7732226af26bf99f19e2cffe0ae219db5b/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/2f437f37bb265d9f8f1392823dbca12d2bec06d6/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging/3.1.3.GA/64499e907f19e5e1b3fdc02f81440c1832fe3545/jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec/1.0.0.Final/1f9fef7a9fcbb41cc390fc370a291cf30729e094/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/e84a2122e76f0b6503be78094ddf2108057ac15f/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.9.5/c3264abeea62c4d2f367e21484fbb40c7e256393/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.objenesis/objenesis/1.3/dc13ae4faca6df981fc7aeb5a522d9db446d5d50/objenesis-1.3.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.7/56003dcd0a31deea6391b9e2ef2f2dc90b205a92/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.7/def21bc1a6e648ee40b41a84f1db443132913105/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.7/d521cb26a9c4407caafcec302e7804b048b07cea/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/2b8019b6249bb05d81d3a3094e468753e2b21311/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-actuator/1.0.2.RELEASE/ec33fd737d646dc4e092176bee856245e2f02f8c/spring-boot-actuator-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.0.2.RELEASE/3a70e3021aec334ee8b1a454ea791d27997a7191/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator/1.0.2.RELEASE/699771411accffc41656db59ae51dd6663a653d6/spring-boot-starter-actuator-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.0.2.RELEASE/58b239d692c4fab48dc8c430eabd527a2e153816/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.0.2.RELEASE/184c72d3b88d7b15428c17e93de9f33e1a44653b/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.0.2.RELEASE/d25eacb4965c4902d12878caf6f6f8904143e415/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.0.2.RELEASE/47a20c5bad47916ca99d768782de12c54b707a00/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/1.0.2.RELEASE/ccab7d782c8a8bf95c06573edd2f40d7da332e36/spring-boot-starter-test-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.0.2.RELEASE/6aed407ba99a2820a6b615ee3accb27ba5ef4529/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.0.2.RELEASE/fb26276f8400658e15d571350c5b577dfe40567a/spring-boot-starter-web-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter/1.0.2.RELEASE/a6cbc3adc8d95a0e5405d3c1ca30ad8e6bed1cf1/spring-boot-starter-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/1.0.2.RELEASE/8d1a06e468b16577075db27123091758b6f880af/spring-boot-1.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons/1.7.2.RELEASE/ccaf8f785382bdef27a0c287d2d75af7e5c8dccf/spring-data-commons-1.7.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa/1.5.2.RELEASE/6e8608622fd11205238d8d1363f099c2a638a0bf/spring-data-jpa-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-core/2.0.2.RELEASE/5ce1944206f5d4d77791c441f597f23d8f6908a7/spring-data-rest-core-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.data/spring-data-rest-webmvc/2.0.2.RELEASE/2c87a7f69609046a3ef6da9cc9621176fd22c30d/spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.hateoas/spring-hateoas/0.9.0.RELEASE/18872c263352a7d240d3dd3f6a0560f89a2fa2c5/spring-hateoas-0.9.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.0.0.RELEASE/c2822de989fc30e1ebf88eed3839af0d696af091/spring-plugin-core-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aop/4.0.3.RELEASE/dcedf5329d7092d66cc9d2496687a5f29d883eb6/spring-aop-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-aspects/4.0.3.RELEASE/e0a8f3dbaffe501cc95f12365ea6751e629237c6/spring-aspects-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-beans/4.0.3.RELEASE/41eabd53fd4ba5ba2b2d8af6c256a3741f65c2f3/spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-context/4.0.3.RELEASE/782a71a312dc307fa531023aa66247b9b4a109d/spring-context-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/4.0.3.RELEASE/138d28200d97f4affe9ccaa47fab54718b438319/spring-core-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-expression/4.0.3.RELEASE/40b25b3a693cb4cc382ddf2e69ff1b29c75a2e7d/spring-expression-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.0.3.RELEASE/5c86b94f15523b3b125c35861aeb4ca85897231a/spring-jdbc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-orm/4.0.3.RELEASE/92220b99c3a8b576286c10edd1726f837450bc2c/spring-orm-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-test/4.0.3.RELEASE/76b870a5aa132b4c0dd78cd061feb3e1652cddd1/spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-tx/4.0.3.RELEASE/83dfa294b89feda22caba2842cdc32729554dd86/spring-tx-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-web/4.0.3.RELEASE/4d5066f31ea4b9c58957bf8c0c213b13ed44c1c5/spring-web-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-webmvc/4.0.3.RELEASE/d6fd9778619ab87a41ae3aa879a53ee60f160c08/spring-webmvc-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.13/73cbb494a912866c4c831a178c3a2a9169f4eaad/snakeyaml-1.13.jar, file:/Users/binay/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/3136ca936f64c9d68529f048c2618bd356bf85c9/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/Users/binay/Desktop/android_part1/android5/mobilecloud-15-master-2/assignments/assignment2/lib/mobilecloud.handin-1.0.0.jar, file:/Users/binay/Desktop/android_part1/android5/mobilecloud-15-master-2/assignments/assignment2/lib/video.up.test-1.0.0.jar]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at org.magnum.dataup.Application.main(Application.java:47)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:270)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:145)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:159)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:132)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[-1]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:79)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: What is on this line? `org.magnum.dataup.Application.main(Application.java:47)`

Comment: SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're running an old version of Spring Boot?

Comment: Might be worth having a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21977030/658663

Comment: Check that you do not have running an other tomcat instance.

Answer (score 0):

You already have an open tomcat instance, try first to terminate the old one, then reopen it, check the photo applied.

[image]